# Should I commit gitignore at private repository

Tags: github

Should I commit gitignore at GitHub in my private repository?

I am working on project with my friend for easily sharing of files I want to upload all at GitHub.
If I don't initialise .gitignore at my private repository, is it going any issues with privacy of my project?

Comment: Yes Sure it will

Answer (score 0):

A private project would remain private with or without a `.gitignore` in it.

But the content of the .gitignore itself could be sensitive.
That is why you can list a folder in that .gitignore: that would ignore *all* files within that folder, without you having to list those files, whose name could be revelatory.

```
 afolder/
```